# sortUsingFunction and "void value not ignored as it ought to be"

Tags: objective-c

In my objective c class, I'd like to sort an array like this:

```
NSArray *sorted = [unsortedArray sortUsingFunction: mySort context: NULL];
```

My sort function is implemented as:

```
NSInteger mySort(id one, id two, void *ctx) { return 1; }
```

When I build the program the compiler tells me:

```
error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
```

Now I think I know what the compiler is trying to tell me:

*"I don't know what the heck "mySort" is so I will assume it returns 'void'. Oops, looks like you are trying to assign 'void' to a variable, nope can't do that. Try again."*

Alright, Mr. compiler, what in the world to I have to tell you so you know the function prototype is *NSInteger mySort(id, id, void*)*? I tried putting that line in the class header file, before the "@interface", after, pretty much all over the place, but I can't get this to work.

Where/how do I have to declare the function prototype for my sort function?

Big thanks in advance,
Mark.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sortUsingFunction:` is an NSMutableArray method that re-orders the array object and does not return a value. It looks like you're looking for `sortedArrayUsingFunction:`, an NSArray method that returns a sorted, autoreleased shallow copy of the array.